# Displaying an image from SQL Server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, image

I am need to display an image on my asp.net page, which is stored as an image data type in SQL Server. I am looking at this post, [display/retrieve image from sql database in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413476/display-retrieve-image-from-sql-database-in-vb-net), however, how can I display that image in a `<td>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<td>` tags can't be used to display images unless you put an `<img>` element inside it. With that said, this is how you display an image in VB.NET from code behind:

Having this type of markup in your aspx page:

```
<td> 
<img src="" runat="server" id="imageFromDB" />
...
```

You can do this in code behind:

```
Dim imageBytes() as Byte= ...  // You got the image from the db here...
//jpg is used as an example on the line below. 
//You need to use the actual type i.e. gif, jpg, png, etc.
//You can do imageFromDB simply because you set runat="server" on the markup
imageFromDB.src = String.Format("data:image/{0};base64,
{1}","jpg",Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)
```

And this will render your image on the page.

I hope I've given you enough information here.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the sample in the answer you mention:

```
<td><img src="PathToYourHttpHandler?id=ID_OF_YOUR_IMAGE" /></td>
```