# Display image from database in a datagrid with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, datagridview

I'm using a MySql database with 2 fields: a dossiernumber and a field where I save the name and location of a image. I want to place a datagrid on my winform and show a image (thumbnail) in the first cell and the dossiernumber in the second cell, but can't get it working.

The pictures don't show and leave only missing picture link. I also can't place the picture in the first cell. This is what it looks like:

[image]

What is wrong?

This is the code I've written:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1


    'ALLES OM DATAGRID TE PLAATSEN

    'GLOBALE DECLARATIES
    Dim conString As String = "server=localhost;userid=root;database=testvehicle"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(conString)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable()


    Private Sub Form1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
        retrieve()
    End Sub



    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2
        DataGridView1.Width = 410
        'CONSTRUCT IMAGE COLUMN
        Dim imgCol As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn()
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Image"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgCol)
            'CONSTRUCT DATA COLUMNS
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "dossiernr"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 100
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect
    End Sub

    'ALLES OM DATAGRID TE VULLEN

    'PROCEDURE POPULATE ROW
    Private Sub populate(foto1 As String, product_dossiernr As String)
        Dim row As String() = New String() {foto1, product_dossiernr}
        'ADD ROW TO ROWS
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    End Sub

'DATA ONTVANGEN

    Private Sub retrieve()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        'SQL STATEMENT
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT foto1, product_dossiernr FROM producten ORDER BY product_dossiernr"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
        'OPEN CON, RETRIEVE, FILL DATAGRID
        Try
            con.Open()
            adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            adapter.Fill(dt)
            For Each row In dt.Rows
                populate(row(0), row(1))
            Next
            con.Close()
            dt.Rows.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

'EINDE DATAGRID VULLEN

End Class
```

Comment: First item under **Related** on the right: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2413476/1070452

Answer (score 0):

in your code it looks like your naming your column the image name, not assigning it a picture value so this is why your getting the name and not the image.

here is s snippet of code I used before that works pretty well.

```
Dim ColImage As New DataGridViewImageColumn
Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell

'Set Name
ColImage.Name = "ColImg"

'Set Header text
ColImage.HeaderText = "Your Image!"

'Add column to datagridview
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(ColImage)

'Set image value
Img.Value = Image.FromFile("C:\YourImage.png")

'Add the image cell to a row
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Add(Img)
```